# Joining tables based on loosely defined free text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2008-r2

I have would like to join tables based on loosely honoured business rules

I have appointment data in the following format.

- Some appointments are linked into *Client ID*, whereas others are not.
- All appointments will have the last name and first name in the Appointment info e.g. Project meeting :Taylor, James  OR [*HE] Taylor,James:
  i.e The Lastname and Firstname separated by comma with with out without space either side will be in the Appointment Column

The Appointment Table looks like this

```
ID| AppointmentTime         | Appointment                           |Client ID
23| 2019-09-30 09:15:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL  
34| 2019-09-30 09:20:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL
35| 2019-09-30 09:25:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL
36| 2019-09-30 10:25:00.000 | Pre sales : Hayes, John               | 2
47| 2019-09-30 10:30:00.000 | Project meeting :Manning, Richard     |425
50| 2019-09-30 14:30:00.000 | Closure meeting :Kuruvita, Peter      | NULL
```

The Client Table looks like this

```
ID  | Last Name | First Name 
2   | Hayes     | John               
425 | Manning   |Richard
3   | Taylor    | James
```

I want to be able to join Client Table with Appointment table based on the below rules

1. Use Client ID in the Appointment and Client tables where possible
2. Extract last and first names from the Appointment column and join
   based on the same columns in the Client table
3. Where 2. above is not possible due no records in the Client, still display last name and first name from the Appointment column (potentially with another
   column to indicate no match )

Expected results look like this

```
 ClientID    |Client Firstname  |Client Lastname |Match found 
    NULL     |Peter             |Kuruvita        |NO 
    3        |James             |Taylor          |YES
    2        |John              |Hayes           |YES
    425      |Richard           |Manning         |YES
```

Could you please help with a SQL statement or snippets for different parts so that I can piece them together?

The implementation is in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Comment: Is inconsistent data possible, e.g. Appointment = 'Project meeting :Taylor, James', Client ID = 425? If yes, and if such a row existed additionally to the ones you have shown, then we'd have three matches for James Taylor and one mismatch. What shall be shown then in your results?

Answer (score 1):

At its core, this is really a data structure issue, and the optimal solution would be to fix the data input so that the Appointment table is split into two columns (one designating the type of appointment and the other with the client name). If your data gets loaded into the database from an Excel sheet or Google sheet, this should be extremely easy to fix and will eliminate the hardest part of this query, which is cleaning up the data.

Fixing a problematic table with a query is never as desirable as fixing the table and then running a simple query.

Assuming you've already tried that route and are not able to get the table changed, here's one approach that uses a temporary table with a case statement to "stage" the data. It's ugly. My manager would be horrified if I ever deployed a query like this on live data at work. But it will get you a usable output. My strategy was to rip out the substring values. Be aware that this strategy will fail and the query will break if your data is not inputted consistently.

While we're on the subject, it's best practice not to include spaces in your column names (bad = [Client Name]. good = [client_name]). This helps to avoid breakages.

```
/*I created two temp tables to show more clearly what is happening with the data.
 In the first temp table, we create a column called client_name that includes only
 the characters after the ':' in the Appointment column.
 SUBSTRING() extracts all characters after the colon.
 LTRIM() trims off any leading spaces, since some rows have them and others don't;
 for instance, ': Hayes' has a space but ':Kuruvita' does not.
 */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #apptstaging
SELECT 
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Appointment, CHARINDEX(':',Appointment)+1, LEN(Appointment))) AS client_name
    ,ID
    ,AppointmentTime
    ,[Client ID]
INTO #apptstaging
FROM [Appointment]

/* In this second query, I pulled out everything after the first comma, and assume 
that the comma has a space after it. This is the first name. Then, I pull out the
last name from all the characters before the first comma.
Again, creating multiple temp tables is somewhat redundant, but I'm doing it to make
it clear what I'm doing with the data. */

drop table if exists #namestaging
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(client_name, CHARINDEX(',',client_name)+2, (LEN(client_name)-(CHARINDEX(',',client_name)))) as First_Name 
    ,SUBSTRING(client_name, 1, CHARINDEX(',',client_name)-1) AS Last_Name
    ,a.*
into #namestaging
from #apptstaging

/*The case statement returns 'Yes' if the name has a match in the Client table.
I then join the temp table to the Client table.*/

SELECT
     ns.[client ID]
    ,ns.First_Name
    ,ns.Last_Name
    ,CASE 
         WHEN c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
         END AS 'Match Found'
FROM #namestaging ns
     LEFT JOIN [Client] c
        ON c.[last name] = ns.last_name
        AND c.[first name] = ns.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You were told already, that your real issue is a data structure problem. So I will not talk about this again. If you can change this (might be, this issue is the attempt to change this), you really should...

Well, I'd go this route (in v2008, which is *outdated*...)

Your data in a *mockup-scenario*:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT,AppointmentTime DATETIME,Appointment VARCHAR(1000),ClientID INT);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (23,'2019-09-30T09:15:00.000','Project meeting :Taylor, James    ', NULL)  
,(34,'2019-09-30T09:20:00.000','Project meeting :Taylor, James    ', NULL)
,(35,'2019-09-30T09:25:00.000','Project meeting :Taylor, James    ', NULL)
,(36,'2019-09-30T10:25:00.000','Pre sales : Hayes, John           ', 2)
,(47,'2019-09-30T10:30:00.000','Project meeting :Manning, Richard ',425)
,(50,'2019-09-30T14:30:00.000','Closure meeting :Kuruvita, Peter  ', NULL);
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT t.*
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CastedAndSplit.value('/x[2]/y[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)'))) AS LastName
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CastedAndSplit.value('/x[2]/y[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)'))) AS FirstName
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x><y>' +  REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT t.Appointment AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</y><y>'),':','</y></x><x><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)) A(CastedAndSplit);
```

The result

```
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| ID | AppointmentTime         | Appointment                       | ClientID | FirstName | LastName |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 23 | 2019-09-30 09:15:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James    | NULL     | Taylor    | James    |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 34 | 2019-09-30 09:20:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James    | NULL     | Taylor    | James    |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 35 | 2019-09-30 09:25:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James    | NULL     | Taylor    | James    |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 36 | 2019-09-30 10:25:00.000 | Pre sales : Hayes, John           | 2        | Hayes     | John     |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 47 | 2019-09-30 10:30:00.000 | Project meeting :Manning, Richard | 425      | Manning   | Richard  |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 50 | 2019-09-30 14:30:00.000 | Closure meeting :Kuruvita, Peter  | NULL     | Kuruvita  | Peter    |
+----+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

The idea in short:

The `CROSS APPLY` will use a trick with XML to split your string first at the `:` and then at the `,`. The resulting XML will look like one of these:

```
<x>
  <y>Project meeting </y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>Manning</y>
  <y> Richard </y>
</x>
```

We can use the XPath `/x[2]` to get the part after the `:` and the `/y[1]` or `/y[2]` to grab the first or the second name fragment. The rest is trimming...

I leave it up to you to articulate the join to your client table, that should be easy...